# How can I import content to Drupal 7 using drush?

Tags: drupal-7, drush

How can I import content (not users) to Drupal 7 by using drush ?

Comment: A nice tutorial about that can be see in https://www.drupal.org/node/1561820.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using migrate module,we can create a script to import content.
After that using drush commands to import content.

drush mi --help